# Need guidance on paginating through this URL using Python (requests, beautifulsoup or selenium) OR Javascript (node js, puppeteer)?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, selenium, beautifulsoup

So i was trying to scrape data from the following URL:

https://www.11880.com/suche/Immobilienmakler/deutschland?branchen=3302469%7C3302464%7C3302249%7C3303516%7C3301609%7C3300129&sorte=%7C&modul=direct

I am good at Web Scraping myself but this website is having some unique type of pagination which i guess is done using JavaScript. In fact for the first 5 pages it just appends `page={NO}` to the URL but after the first 5 pages it appends a unique identifier (query) to URL of each page along with the Page No. Most of the part of that query is similar for all pages just some characters are different to each page.

The query looks like this:

For Page 6:

`cmxXakxKcWNvelMwbko5aFZ3YzdWemtjb0p5MFZ3YmtBRmp2b1RTbXFSOXZuekl3cVBWNnJsV3NuSkR2QnZWMU1KSDVNUU5sQlRWMkFUU3dCSld4TEdMM0JReDRabU52WVBXc3BUeXhWd2JsWkdxOXNGanZwMkl1cHpBYkczTzBuSjlocGxWNnIzMGZWYVd1b3pFaW9JQXlNSkR2Qno1MW9Uazk=`

For Page 7:

`cmxXakxKcWNvelMwbko5aFZ3YzdWemtjb0p5MFZ3YmtBRmp2b1RTbXFSOXZuekl3cVBWNnJsV3NuSkR2QnZWMU1RcDJaVFYxWjJaakx3cDBNSkQyWndaM0FUVjNMd3R2WVBXc3BUeXhWd2JrQUdNOXNGanZwMkl1cHpBYkczTzBuSjlocGxWNnIzMGZWYVd1b3pFaW9JQXlNSkR2Qno1MW9Uazk=`

**Python Requests**

I have checked into the code through inspect and was not able to find any such key for the next page. The current page query is there in script tags.

Try this code to start with. this is for 7th page. You can see the `query` in the `params` which i took from `Network` tab.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.11880.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': '__cfduid=d3ba308b5d5994136cfb2ffd23797ae371615711538; _gcl_au=1.1.638363378.1615711421; _ga=GA1.2.1798619679.1615711421; _gid=GA1.2.1401311919.1615711421; __gads=ID=7767acb88c5bd4d2:T=1615721793:S=ALNI_MZzcwQtHCl4hWOWahxyceRZJYrgGg; randomSeed=1615724814; referrer=none; __cf_bm=d8225bc8662e1af83b9ae8c3eebbfdb7f0613cb2-1615727481-1800-AdDP/tSscGJQRiVmW/GyJBUUNHXkWvqYbiqv47MgKrvXzBt0InecHvXrwnMtnOKbtYS/YODx2Zh1ewlOlCAgtMpvjD7Vw9FG9J+gvII/EOy2; cf_chl_2=93a30b70f062111; cf_chl_prog=a41; cf_clearance=b85ac9756885d88ad6c979309aeadb222e4f60b9-1615727532-0-250; geoIPData=eyJjb3VudHJ5X2NvZGUiOm51bGwsImNvdW50cnlfY29kZTMiOm51bGwsImNvdW50cnlfbmFtZSI6bnVsbCwicmVnaW9uIjpudWxsLCJjaXR5IjpudWxsLCJwb3N0YWxfY29kZSI6bnVsbCwibGF0aXR1ZGUiOm51bGwsImxvbmdpdHVkZSI6bnVsbCwiYXJlYV9jb2RlIjpudWxsLCJkbWFfY29kZSI6bnVsbCwibWV0cm9fY29kZSI6bnVsbCwiY29udGluZW50X2NvZGUiOm51bGwsImlwIjoiMTE5LjE2MC42Ni4xMjUsIDE3Mi42OS4xMTEuMTM4In0%3D; rlData={%22randomSeed%22:1615724814%2C%22rlUrl%22:%22/suche/Immobilienmakler/deutschland?branchen=3302469%257C3302464%257C3302249%257C3303516%257C3301609%257C3300129&sorte=%257C&modul=direct&page=5%22%2C%22adsTargeting%22:{%22ort%22:[%22deutschland%22]%2C%22suche%22:[%22Immobilienmakler%22]%2C%22url%22:[%22/suche/Immobilienmakler/deutschland%22]%2C%22branche%22:[%223302469%22%2C%223302464%22%2C%223302249%22%2C%223303516%22%2C%223301609%22%2C%223300611%22%2C%223305630%22%2C%223300129%22%2C%223305491%22%2C%223305627%22]}}',
}

params = (
    ('branchen', '3302469|3302464|3302249|3303516|3301609|3300129'),
    ('sorte', '|'),
    ('modul', 'direct'),
    ('page', '7'),
    ('query', 'cmxXakxKcWNvelMwbko5aFZ3YzdWemtjb0p5MFZ3YmtBRmp2b1RTbXFSOXZuekl3cVBWNnJsV3NuSkR2QnZWMU1RcDJaVFYxWjJaakx3cDBNSkQyWndaM0FUVjNMd3R2WVBXc3BUeXhWd2JrQUdNOXNGanZwMkl1cHpBYkczTzBuSjlocGxWNnIzMGZWYVd1b3pFaW9JQXlNSkR2Qno1MW9Uazk='),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.11880.com/suche/Immobilienmakler/deutschland', headers=headers, params=params)
```

**Python Selenium**

I tried with selenium but the website is having a captcha which pops up when i do `driver.get(url)` and i don't know how to bypass the captcha.

**JavaScript OR Node**

I haven't tried with JavaScript but i guess the captcha will pop up there too.

**So any solution in any technology that are mentioned above, will be highly appreciated. Thank You...**

Comment: So you are seeking help bypassing `CAPTCHA` which is completely illegal. `CAPTCHA` is implied in order to prevent bots !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη i just need some guidance on, how can i paginate, basically.

Comment: @AhmadFaraz check my answer. It's simple solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple.

Just send request like in this form, from each page. This POST request redirects users to the necessary page.
[image: screencast]

Comment: Thank You for the answer